# Enabling CDC in SQL Server 2005 won't work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-rds, database-administration

I am trying to use AWS replicate following this tutorial - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html#CHAP_Source.SQLServer.CDC.Publication .

Using this code on a 2005 Microsoft SQL table

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_cdc_enable_db 'databasename';
```

Results in

> Could not find stored procedure 'msdb.dbo.rds_cdc_enable_db'.

This is the driver currently

> MS SQL Server / SQL Server (Old driver, jTDS)

Any idea on how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDC is not available in SQLServer 2005. It's in 2008 onward (enterprise edition until 2016 SP1, where it's also available in standard edition)

Comment: Thanks for this - what can i do instead to use AWS migrate?

Comment: Ask Amazon - it's their tool? I doubt you will get far trying to migrate(?) (or replicate - not clear what your goal is) to/from an ancient, unsupported version of sql server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the **database name** instead of table name..

```sql
exec msdb.dbo.rds_cdc_enable_db 'DB_name'
```

Use trigger as an alternative to CDC. as mentioned by geofftnz, You can only use CDC on version 2008 and up. btw, SQL Server 2005 is out of support, you maybe need to upgrade to higher version of SQL Server. check the link for supported version of RDS SQL Server version [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html#SQLServer.Concepts.General.VersionSupport)